# Wrong Particle Rotation?

Tags: particles

I wanted to use a particle system in my recent blend file and came across an issue that I am not sure how to fix. The object I wanted to be duplicated by the particle system has a material with a gradient (set to easing) texture. When I set the Render as Object in the particle settings the rotation of the duplicated objects isn't quite correct and the options available for rotation didn't have the desired effect. I know that you can rotate the instance object in edit mode to fix that, but: When I do that the gradient doesn't move with the rotation.

Any clues on how to fix this kind of issue?

[image]

Ok here is the material setup.

---

[image]

Ok here is the material setup.

Comment: Rotate -90 on the X axis to align it for the particle system.  You can use a mapping node on the shader to match rotation

Answer (score 1):

You can either fix the gradient in your material or enable the *Object Rotation* option in the *Particle* settings, and rotate your particle object in *Object* mode, which probably won't affect your material:

[image]

Comment: Hm, sadly the option in the particle settings doesn't change it. Also, rotating the object in object mode doens't affect the particles. But how do I fix the gradient in the material, I think this might help. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: could you please show your material setup?

Comment: ok I just figured it out actually. The object rotation does indeed work. I was just to stupid to understand how. Thanks for your help. Very much appreciated!

Comment: ok great then  ;)